# Polymer 2 upgrade: "this.getPropertyInfo is not a function"

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, polymer-2.x

I have a Polymer application that I want to upgrade to Polymer 2 (rc7 at time of asking).

I have a `<paper-spinner-lite>` that throws an exception :

> `paper-spinner-behavior.html:65 Uncaught TypeError: this.getPropertyInfo is not a function`

What can I do to work around or fix this?

Comment: paper spinner may not be ready for 2.x... did you try the 2.0-preview branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Polymer 2.0 installation Documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/about_20#elements).

Have you installed paper-spinner with bower correctly?

```
bower install --save PolymerElements/paper-spinner#2.0-preview
```